# Boolean parameters in methods. Why not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reek

I'm using `reek` as an analyzing tool for best practices in my code. However recently I found that if in the method, I have boolean parameters, such as.

```
def method (flag = true)
```

`reek` gives me a warning. Why does `reek` tell me that it is a warning?

Comment: Most likely since a method taking only a boolean usually should be split into two, for example a `SetEnabled(bool)` could be split into an `Enable`and a `Disable` that make more sense.

Comment: Joachim, I would argue its OK to pass a boolean as a value to be saved, like you might set an integer with a setter method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of years before I wrote reek I blogged about this code smell here:

[http://silkandspinach.net/2004/07/15/avoid-boolean-parameters/](https://web.archive.org/web/20220314024954/https://silkandspinach.net/2004/07/15/avoid-boolean-parameters/)

The problems with Boolean parameters all have to do with duplication and the SRP: the called method has two responsibilities, and the caller knows which one it wants to invoke.

Comment: That's a gross exaggeration in my opinion. There are tons of cases when a method with a Boolean parameter complies with SRP. Like `def import(ignore_errors)`, etc.

Comment: Indeed, I strongly disagree with this smell. Its case dependent. What if the method that has the branch needs to be called from different places. The surrounding code then needs to implement the branch condition and results in code duplication. The same can be true of any branch condition, not just boolean.

Comment: You likely need to write some code to decide what to pass in as the boolean value in the first place, so there's no less duplication than separating the condition inside the called method into two methods.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I thought I'd add my thoughts for people who come in from google:

Separate methods are fine in some cases, but the better option generally in my mind is following:

```
def method(option = {:flag => false})
  options[:flag] ? doFoo : doBar
end

method(:flag => true)
```

This also could include a check if the flag is actually a boolean:

```
def method(option = {:flag => false})
  flag = options.fetch(:flag) { false }
  unless [true, false].include?(flag)
    raise ArgumentError, ':flag option should be true or false'   
  end
  flag? doFoo : doBar
end

method(:flag => true)
```

Answer (score 0):

A flag variable is considered bad practice. This is because it inherently violates the principle that functions should do one, and only one, thing. By passing in a boolean flag you are saying, "Do this if it's true, and that if it's false", which is two things.

Comment: but functions always do different things depending on their parameters.

Comment: @joshua.paling - I realize this comment comes many years after your comment, so take this for what it is. It's the difference between, "Here's a function, and the parameters are what they are," vs. "Here's two functions inside a function, and this boolean selects which function is actually used." By removing the boolean you remove an extra mental jump that the reader of the code has to make in order to understand what behavior will actually be executed, by trying to make the chosen function clear at the point of invocation.

Comment: Hopefully it's not a ruby best practice that any function that needs to handle a boolean should be split into two functions. That is definitely an anti-pattern. Imagine repeating that with n-booleans. By that logic, you'll need 2^n different functions.

Answer (score 0):

To create default Boolean parameters in Ruby that passes Linters check like RuboCop use:

```
def method (flag: true)
end
```

then call like this:

```
method (flag: true)
method (flag: false)
```

the most important thing to note is that any method definition that has optional parameters must be called with the **names of all the optional arguments specified**.